# How to check if a text contains a telephone number with javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I would like to check, if a text contains a telephone number or not.

```
Regex = /\d{6,}/;
```

This would check for 6 digits in a row, but phone numbers can also contain space, +, (, ), -, . and slash...

How would I check against any kind of telephone number?

I would like to detect numbers in these forms:

```
+49 123 456789
0049 123456789
(040) 132 45 67
040/123 456
040-132-12
040 123456
+49 (0)40-123456
```

Comment: This may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6195458/phone-number-validation-javascript

There are probably a handful of other solutions on this site somewhere.

Comment: Where I live, mobile numbers are 10 digits, usually presented in a blocks of 4, 3, 3 digits separated by spaces. Fixed line phones are 8 digits in two blocks of 4 and may or may not have a two digit area code, usually presented in brackets. Other places have different formats.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not 100% possible to serve all cases, and you  probably have to adapt it to your needs, but for example this regular expression will do the job:

```
var Regex = /\b[\+]?[(]?[0-9]{2,6}[)]?[-\s\.]?[-\s\/\.0-9]{3,15}\b/m;
```

Here is an example how it works:

```js
function check_for_phone(){
    
      var message = document.getElementById("a").value;
      var Regex = /\b[\+]?[(]?[0-9]{2,6}[)]?[-\s\.]?[-\s\/\.0-9]{3,15}\b/m; 
       
      alert( Regex.test(message) ); 
      // This will alert 'true' if the textarea contains a phonenumber 
}
```

```html
<textarea id="a">please call me: 040 12345</textarea>
<input type="button" onclick="check_for_phone()"  value="check for telephone">
```

*found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29767609/1069083*

Comment: I fixed the error, please remove the downvote

Answer (score 1):

This would <s>be impossible</s> not be feasible. There are simply too many different lengths and formats of phone numbers all over the world. You should instead focus on a certain subset of formats/lengths that you are willing to accept.

If that still leaves you with too many options, you might need to just go for a simple check like this:

- non-null
- Includes only these characters:

  - `0-9`
  - `+`
  - `[space]`